# SunCertBuilderException in VS Code/Karate/Java/Maven framework

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, karate, maven-plugin

Trying to find a solution for the error in my framework for over a month now.

We have Karate/Cucumber project in VS code using Maven/Java, after cloning it to my machine, only me from our team can’t run

**mvn clean install ** command

I’m getting Build Failure with SunCertBuilderException PKIX path building failed, getting error plugin maven clean or one of its dependencies could not be resolved, failed to read artifact descriptor (attached screenshots)

Has anybody experienced with it? Tech support in our company didn’t help at all and closed tickets on it.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H15E1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyh65.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z31Jv.png)

We tried to update java/maven versions, updated plugins, checked env variables, also tried to disable certificate with
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true.

But nothing works

Comment: that's interesting. see if this gives you a hint: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/243#issuecomment-343545117 - the other thing I would try is to delete my local maven repository (`~/.m2`) and try again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu problem in the error SunCertPathBuilder Exception and how to resolve it, I’ve attached screenshots.

Comment: @PeterThomas yeah..already tried to delete .m2, update settings.xml :/

Comment: @mel-cyber sorry no other ideas :| one last thing - the official karate vs code extension actually embeds Karate + a JRE. if your feature file does not need to call into java code, it would be good to know if you can get a test to work. if it does, we can narrow down the problem to your JVM: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate

Comment: Add the SSL/TLS certificate of the remote repository to the Java keystore: You can use the keytool command to add the SSL/TLS certificate of the remote repository to the Java keystore.